# ROR code is not being deployed on linode with strange error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, linode

I have successfully installed and configured apache with passenger for deploying a rails application. I installed the 'mysql' and 'rails' gems successfully, but when I run any rake commands like

```
rake db:create
```

to create the database, I get this error

```
Illegal instruction
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Is the 'rake' gem in your bundle? Check `bundle show`.

Comment: See if you can run `rake db:create -t`. If this works, post the trace that you get.

Comment: same result illegal instruction.actually i have two project in rails app folder in which two rails app.1 blog and 2 serach_sport.If i give commnd rake -T then options appear.but when i give this command in blog directory then no option availsble of rake command and also rails s give same error illegal instruction

Comment: So, your directories look like `app: { blog1: {app, config, db, Gemfile...}, search_sport: {app, config, db, Gemfile, ...} }`?

Comment: there are two projects in /root/rails_app folder